# How enter a trade if the SMA9 is > than SMA50 by a certain percentage

Tags: pine-script

Pinescript question. I only want to enter a trade if the SMA9 is > than SMA50 by a certain percentage. Every time I try to multiply by a percentage is does not work.

This is essentially what I am trying sma9*1.2 > sma50 wanting to enter when sma9[0] is 20% greater than sma50
or even this (close[0]*1.2)>close[1]) wanting to enter when close [0] is 20% greater than close[1]

This is what my code looks like.

```
//@version=3
strategy("Nifty SMA Trend",  pyramiding=0, initial_capital=1000, 
default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value=100, overlay=true)
s1 = input(9, title="SMA 1")
s2 = input(50, title="SMA 2")
y = input(2020, title="Year")
sma9= sma(close, s1)
plot(sma9, color=black, linewidth=1)
sma50= sma(close, s2)
plot(sma50, color=red, linewidth=1)
if year >= y
if (close > sma9 and sma9 > sma50 and close>close[1] and sma50>sma50[1] and (close[0]*1.2)>close[1])
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
if(close < sma9 and sma9 < sma50 or sma9<sma9[2])
    strategy.close("Long")
```

Answer (score 0):

20% is a very big change for the price, and even more so for a simple moving average.
Try to reduce the percentage consistently 20 -> 15 -> 10 -> 5 -> 2 -> 1 stop when you are satisfied with the number of enters.